# Sidekiq - Sinatra - Can't read from my ActiveRecord Objects

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sidekiq, sinatra-activerecord

For some reason, my sidekiq worker can't read from my ActiveRecord models. Here is my worker class. It fails on line where its trying to read from my User object: `name = User.find_by(id: user_id).first_name`.

```
require 'gcm'

module Socio
    class RequestNotificationWorker
        include Sidekiq::Worker
        sidekiq_options retry: false

        def perform(target_token, key)
            begin
                gcm = GCM.new(key)
                registration_ids= [target_token]
                options = {notification: {title: "Connection request!", body: "You have a new Socio request.",
                                          sound: "default", badge: 1, type: "1"},
                           collapse_key: "New Connections", content_available: true,  priority: "high"}
                gcm.send(registration_ids, options)
                {success: true}
            rescue => e
                {success: false, error: e.to_s}
            end
        end
    end

    class ConfirmNotificationWorker
        include Sidekiq::Worker
        sidekiq_options retry: false

        def perform(target_token, key)
            begin
                gcm = GCM.new(key)
                name = User.find_by(id: @user_id).first_name
                registration_ids= [target_token]
                options = {notification: {title: "Connection Confirmed!", body: "#{name} has accepted your Socio request.",
                                          sound: "default", badge: 1, type: "2"},
                           collapse_key: "New Connections", content_available: true,  priority: "high"}
                gcm.send(registration_ids, options)
                {success: true}.to_json
            rescue => e
                {success: false, error: e.to_s}
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Also here is my procfile: 
`web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -c 5 -v -r ./app/sidekiq.rb`

And here is the error message:

```
Failed uninitialized constant Socio::ConfirmNotificationWorker::User
```

I tried different require and include commands, but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere inside app/sidekiq.rb you need to require activerecord and user.rb. If you show us your sidekiq.rb it will help.

Comment: Just edited my question, now the code has everything I have in app/sidekiq.rb

Answer (score 0):

This is because `app/sidekiq` is not initializing your application - you have probably all relevant `require` statements in the main application file (`app.rb`). Compare `app/sidekiq.rb` with `app.rb` file (and possible other files in the tree) and add relevant `require` instructions in the first one.

You can also start the console session (for example using [Pry](http://pryrepl.org): `pry -r ./app/sidekiq.rb` or built-in irb: `irb -r ./app/sidekiq.rb`) with `app/sidekiq` and check if all needed classes are there or even better: write specs to check if it works fine.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I added these require statements:

' require 'active_record'
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/activerecord'
require 'json' '

I got the following error:

Failed uninitialized constant Socio::ConfirmNotificationWorker::User

Comment: Some files are missing (for user). Also there is no need of requiring sinatra lib.